# CRC32 correction algorithm C

Tags: c, algorithm, crc, crc32

I've been looking for a CRC32 algorithm, but all I find just give me Checksum algorithms. What I want is a CRC32 algorithm that sends data bits, checks and corrects them. For example:

```
User input: "A" { 01000001 }
I intentionally cause an error so data sent is: "C" { 01000011 }
```

Is there an algorithm in C that can make the correction so `"C"` can be corrected to `"A"` ? I just find "CRC32 Checksum", but nothing about correction and I don't really understand how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRC is an error-detection code, but it doesn't provide enough information to let you tell *which* bit had the error.

(mcdowella makes a good point in a comment): For a short messages, you might assume that single-bit errors are most likely.  You could brute-force try every bit separately, to see if you get the right CRC by flipping that bit.  Some multi-bit errors will lead this method to find a wrong message that has the same CRC as the original, though.

---

For that you need an error-correction code.  You detect which parts of the input were "erased" using error-detection codes, like a CRC or a stronger hash, but then you use an erasure code to re-generate the bad data from the good data and the redundancy blocks.

See for example [PAR2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAR2) for a complete end-to-end system for files, including a file format.  It uses Reed-Solomon with a GaloisField<2^16> for error correction.

Comment: I needed that clarification. Thanks! :3

Comment: For e.g. single-bit errors in short messages you may be able to use syndrome decoding. CRC32 is linear, so you could compute the difference between the checksum produced by an all-zero message and the checksum produced by each message with just one bit set. If any of those differences matches the difference between the observed and expected checksum in the message received it would be reasonable to suppose that the corresponding single bit position matches an error.